# Build an interface using only the SDL and the C standard library

Tags: c, user-interface, sdl

I need to make a program using only the C standard library and the SDL. I can't use the Windows API or any other library. I need to use only the C language i.e. no C++, no C# etc.
I have really no idea on how to achieve that since I only know to output to the standard output device (console) and files. So I hope you can give me an example on how to open a window with two buttons (custom built): one to exit and one to perform any task.

Comment: Follow this : http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/

Comment: It seems really useful but I don't understand C++ or object oriented programming, that's why I said I needed to use only C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a window: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryVideo%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29

About the buttons, you gotta compare the mouse coords and if the user is clicking on the desired spot to do whatever you want. To get this user input data you gotta use the sdl event handling system. You can learn about it trought sdl's wiki or you check this tutorial http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson04/index.php (i'm sure that there are other tutorials out there if you google it).

To draw the buttons to the sccreen you have to use SDL's rendering system.

Your question is not that specific, so that is the best i can do for you.